# HTML::TableExtract - Script working with a html file but not with the corresponding URL

Tags: html, perl

I am using the following script, which takes as input a HTML page obtained from this url :
http://omim.org/entry/600185

```
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $doc = 'OMIM_2.htm';
my $headers =  [ 'Phenotype', 'Inheritance' ];

my $table_extract = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => $headers);

$table_extract->parse_file($doc);
my ($table) = $table_extract->tables;

for my $row ($table->rows) {
    foreach $info (@$row) {
        if ($info =~ m/(\S+)/) {
             $info =~ s/^\s+(.+)\s+$/$1/;
             print $info."\t";
        }
     }
    print "\n";
}
```

It does what I want, thus extracting the "Phenotype" and "Inheritance" fields from the table.
Nevertheless, I would like to obtain this information directly from the URL, and I tried to modify the script :

```
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $doc = 'http://omim.org/entry/600185';
my $headers =  [ 'Phenotype', 'Inheritance' ];

my $table_extract = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => $headers);

$table_extract->parse($doc);
my ($table) = $table_extract->tables;

for my $row ($table->rows) {
    foreach $info (@$row) {
         if ($info =~ m/(\S+)/) {
             $info =~ s/^\s+(.+)\s+$/$1/;
             print $info."\t";
        }
     }
     print "\n";
}
```

I certainly do a mistake because I obtained the following error :

```
Can't call method "rows" on an undefined value at Test_OMIM.perl line 11.
```

More intriguing, I also obtained this error if the file was called "OMIM_2.html" and no "OMIM_2.htm". Logical ?

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: What makes you think that the parse method can take a URL? Please read the documentation of the module.

Comment: This is not a good question. The documentation can be found at http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TableExtract

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write, especially before asking for help with it

Answer (score 3):

You are giving [`HTML::TableExtract`](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TableExtract) a URL when it wants to be given HTML. In order to download the HTML you would do this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua       = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get('http://omim.org/entry/600185');
my $html     = $response->content;

print $html;
```

### output

```
Your client was identified as a crawler.


Please note:

- The robots.txt files disallows the crawling of the site except to Google, Bing 
  and Yahoo crawlers.

- The raw data is available via FTP on the http://omim.org/downloads link on the site.

- We have an API you can learn about at http://omim.org/api and http://omim.org/help/api, 
  this provides access to the data in XML, JSON, Python and Ruby formats.

- You should feel free to contact us at http://omim.org/contact to figure the best 
  approach to getting the data you need.
```

Please note that you might have difficulties doing this, as `omim.org` does not want you to download the HTML automatically, but wants you to use the raw-data or API. [This is their `robots.txt`](http://omim.org/robots.txt) document, which all automated software is supposed to read and comply with voluntarily

Comment: Thanks for your edit @Borodin. I didn't add `use strict` and `use warnings` as it was meant as part of a script, and not a stand alone script. I don't have any shebang either.

Comment: It's best to add them anywhere you can as it's tough job anyway persuading people to use them. And the shebang line isn't part of the Perl program - it's a shell facility